# How to use the outputs of bert model?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

The bert model gives us the two outputs, one gives us the [batch,maxlen,hiddenstates] and other one is [batch, hidden States of cls token]. But I did not understood when to use the specific output. Can anyone tell  me for which task which output should be used??

Answer (score 2):

The output is usually `[batch, maxlen, hidden_state]`, it can be narrowed down to `[batch, 1, hidden_state]` for `[CLS]` token, as the `[CLS]` token is 1st token in the sequence.  Here , `[batch, 1, hidden_state]` can be equivalently considered as `[batch, hidden_state]`.

Since BERT is transformer based contextual model, the idea is `[CLS]` token would have captured the entire context and would be sufficient for simple downstream tasks such as classification. Hence, for tasks such as classification using sentence representations, you can use `[batch, hidden_state]`. However, you can also consider `[batch, maxlen, hidden_state]`, average across `maxlen` dimension to get averaged embeddings. However, some sequential tasks, such as classification using CNN or RNN requires, sequence of representations, during which you have to rely on  `[batch, maxlen, hidden_state]`. Also, some training objectives such as predicting the masked words, or for SQUAD 1.1 (as shown in BERT paper), the entire sequence of embeddings  `[batch, maxlen, hidden_state]` are used.